# Alignment problem in curriculum

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, two-column, cv, alignment

I would like to align in a tide way the right bit of these references... I'm stucked, I don't understand how can I solve this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks = true,}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=.190\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\hsize=.85\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\hsize=.28\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}

\hyphenpenalty=10000

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\linespread{1.1}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}
\cleanlookdateon

\vbox{
{\large \textsc{\textbf{References}}} \vspace{1mm}
\hrule
\bigskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ss}

\

\textbf{Pinco Pallino}                     &    \textbf{Il Gabibbo}\\
Professor of Ualleranomics                 & Professor of Minchiology \\
Université of Life                         & Facebook University   \\
pinco.pallino@life.be                      & ilgabibbo@striscialanotizia.it \\

\
\

\textbf{Caio Giulio Cesare}                 & \\   
Assistant Professor of Tuquoque             & \\
Universitè of the Coliseum                  & \\
giulio.cesare@congiuradeibruti.it           & \\


\bigskip
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

Right now, you see that the name on the right end side is not aligned with the other one...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using this `\`.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ss}



\textbf{Pinco Pallino}                     &    \textbf{Il Gabibbo}\\
Professor of Ualleranomics                 & Professor of Minchiology \\
Université of Life                         & Facebook University   \\
pinco.pallino@life.be                      & ilgabibbo@striscialanotizia.it \\

& \\

\textbf{Caio Giulio Cesare}                 & \\  
Assistant Professor of Tuquoque             & \\
Universitè of the Coliseum                  & \\
giulio.cesare@congiuradeibruti.it           & \\


\bigskip
\end{tabularx}
```